# Java import all from all

Tags: java, import, package

I have a logical question: Why i cannot import all packages from all packages in java?
For example i can import all classes from java.awt:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

But the following isnt possible:

```
import java.awt.*.*;
```

My aim would be to import all stuff from awt.image and awt.event and so on.
Is there another way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe because it's a bad thing in general to do?  Frankly, the fact that the * operator exists is a design flaw in Java.  You should only import the classes you actually use

Comment: We have to change the compiler to make it work. As of now you can't.

Comment: My guess would be too many clashes. If you import everything, there is bound to be more than 1 class that is named twice. It would lead to ambiguity like crazy. Just a hunch though.

Comment: Let us say that to James Gosling did not like.

Comment: Tip: If you're using Eclipse, click on a class after you type its name, and hit Ctrl + Shift + M.  That'll automatically add the import to your code.  To clean up existing imports, hit ctrl + shift + o

Comment: At compile time the wildcard statements are converted to account for just the needed classes, this makes no difference.

Comment: Java aim of import is to consider only required but not all like include in c, c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to achieve an `import a.package.*.*;` in Java.  The [JLS, Section 7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) specifies the only 4 types of imports that are legal:

> A single-type-import declaration (§7.5.1) imports a single named type,
>   by mentioning its canonical name (§6.7).

e.g. `import java.util.List;`

> A type-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.2) imports all the
>   accessible types (§6.6) of a named type or named package as needed, by
>   mentioning the canonical name of a type or package.

e.g. `import java.awt.*;`

> A single-static-import declaration (§7.5.3) imports all accessible
>   static members with a given name from a type, by giving its canonical
>   name.

e.g. `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;`

> A static-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.4) imports all accessible
>   static members of a named type as needed, by mentioning the canonical
>   name of a type.

e.g. `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`

Packages allow classes of the same name to be referenced individually.  E.g. there is `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`.  What would stop someone from importing everything with `java.*.*;`.  How would `List` be resolved then?  There would be too much ambiguity.

Comment: You make it seem like that ambiguity is unheard of or even disallowed. It is actually fairly common. I've seen java.util.Date and java.sql.Date in the same class many times. The ambiguity is resolved with the full package name. In theory, the same could apply here if Java allowed such a thing.

Comment: Actually, this kind of ambiguity is disallowed.  Try importing `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List` and you'll get a compiler error.  You're right in that specifying `java.util.List` with a fully qualified class name in the actual code removes the ambiguity.  But doing that removes the need for the import at all.

Comment: At the import-statement level, yes. It sounded like you were saying classes with the same name couldn't live in the same file. By the way, how did you get code formatting in your comment? Still learning here.

Comment: @Vidya it's not unheard of but as you said you have to cope with it yourself. If you were allowed to do "import java.*" and that would import everything recursively then the compiler would burst with an error because it would try to import 2x List from different packages. They would need to add a resolution mechanism for that or forbid such imports when ambiguity occurs (and that wouldn't be a useful feature then, imho).

Comment: @Vidya Surround code to go in formatting with backquotes.  E.g. \`test\` yields `test`.

Comment: @Mateusz, I'm not sure where I advocated doing an import of everything. That was the OP. So you're preaching to the choir. I believe in streamlined imports for numerous reasons--mostly related to code quality and, yes, compile time. When you do continuous integration/delivery, compile time matters.

Answer (score 2):

No, and using wildcard imports is bad style in general as it makes your code harder to read.

Comment: not necessarily. Sometimes it actually makes it more readable since you have 1 import instead of 50. Although most IDEs will just collapse that list anyway.

Comment: I have to agree with AFS, and with the advent of IDEs like Eclipse, it will fold them anyway.  If you have that many imports, you are probably violating the cohesion principle and doing to many things in your class.

Comment: that was just an exaggerated example... wildcard does not make your code less readable nor does it make it slower. The only problem might be with namespace collision - this might result in a bit cluttered code since you have to use the fully qualified class name. But then again it's the same situation when you actually have to use 2 classes with the same name...

Comment: If you really want to read code, you start from class not from import.

Answer (score 0):

Some disadvantages of using wildcards imports:

1. Results in including classes that you might not use at all. Not clear picture of what you are working with.
2. More broader scope which is considered bad programming practice.
3. Most important can result in namespace clash. If you are blatantly importing everything from two packages it may result in clash between two classes with same name from different packages.

**Edit**: Seems like importing more classes than required doesn't result in any bulky code, but I would still prefer to import the classes explicitly to have a clear idea about what I am working with.

Comment: and again... Classes which you import but not use are not, in any way, loaded or included in the end.